# Form element disappears inside the blade component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

There's probably something I'm missing when using blade components, but why is my form element not included in the html? If I move it inside one of the `x-slot` it is included.

```
<x-livewire-modal>
    <form action="#" wire:submit.prevent="submit">
        <x-slot name="content"><input type="text" name="title" /></x-slot>
        <x-slot name="footer"><button type="submit">Send</button></x-slot>
    </form>
</x-livewire-modal>
```

Comment: Does your `x-livewire-modal` component have a default `slot`?

Comment: No, do I need that?

Comment: Yes, you'll need a default slot.

Comment: So just add an empty `<x-slot></x-slot>` right after `<x-livewire-modal>` or so?

Comment: Inside your `x-livewire-modal` component, you'll need the magic `$slot` variable. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#slots

Comment: Sorry, I can't get it to work. I edited my code above, but now I get `Undefined variable $slot`

Comment: You put `{{ $slot }}` in the component definition (`resources/views/components/livewire-modal`), not where you use the component.

Comment: Ah I see. Now I got my form in there but it's before the first `x-slot`, not wrapping around both the `x-slots`. Maybe I'm totally missing how these components works. I could move the form to the actual component, but then I need to make the form attributes dynamic.

Comment: Actually, I just made my form wrap around the whole `<x-livewire-modal>` instead. That'll do! Thanks!